# Как разбить запрос на два столбца?

Tags: sql, sqlite, таблицы, преобразование

У меня есть таблица, в которой содержаться игроки, которые участвовати в матчах. Игроки играют в разных командах. Как сделать так, чтобы первая команда была в одном столбце, а другая в другом?
Вот запрос

```
SELECT * from parser_playersinmatches GROUP BY pim_match_id_id, pim_team_id_id;
```

Вот его вывод[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вывод без группировок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот структура БД[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу получить что-то в виде этого: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Где .win и .lose это две команды

Comment: Можно просто сказать, что надо прочитать для решения данной проблемы

Comment: *Вот запрос* Запрос - кривой. Incomplete GROUP BY. Значения любых полей в выходном наборе, кроме `pim_match_id_id, pim_team_id_id` - бессмысленны. Именно эту ошибку и следует исправить. И только потом решать задачу, поставленную в вопросе. Изучайте [SELECT statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), "2.5. Bare columns in an aggregate query"